# Small sized GPG command-line tool for Windows

Tags: windows-xp, gnupg

Where can I find a command-line version of GPG for Windows? It should be small size because [Gpg4win Light](http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html) is 15 MB.

Comment: You can download really small package [gnupg-w32cli-1.4.18.exe](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/binary/gnupg-w32cli-1.4.18.exe) (check that FTP for later versions). After installation it's only 2MB.

Answer (score 2):

You could download it and compile it yourself here:
http://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html

The command line version is included in the GPG4Win, but the installer is actually quite helpful, and I would recommend that myself.  (current gpg2.exe that is included is 769kb)

Also see the light version here:
http://files.gpg4win.org/gpg4win-light-1.0.9.exe

Comment: I would argue that is "lightweight". `gpg2.exe` is indeed small, but when you run it, it requires external tools and libraries. After I have combined everything in a box, I got 12MB. More over when you run `gpg2 --gen-key` it shows a GUI window to ask for password – that's too much for CLI utility.

Comment: ok.  I do not know of a lighter version, good luck.

Comment: I have managed to cut few DLLs and unused EXEs from gpg2 installation, which made it smaller. It's not a good idea to post a download link here, because this is critical software. But if somebody trusts – I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest windows CLI binaries from https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/binary/

Look for `gnupg-w32-2.x.xx_yyyymmdd.exe` e.g. `gnupg-w32-2.2.29_20210704.exe`